# Using selectRaw with DATEADD

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

```
    $data = Trjual_h::where('Kd_Pelanggan',$get)
        ->whereRaw('Nilai_Faktur-Nilai_Bayar > 0')
        ->selectRaw('Nilai_Faktur, Tgl_Faktur,DATEADD(day,Lama_Piutang,Tgl_Faktur) as Jatuh_Tempo, No_Faktur,Nilai_Bayar')
        ->get();
```

So the code return an error that state dateadd isn't a function. Lama_Piutang data type is tinyint(3) and Tgl_Faktur of course dateTime. So where did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATEADD()` is not a function.
`DATE_ADD()` is.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add